# Erro ao retornar no método getView

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou fazendo o *app* em *Action Bar* e estou com um problema ao retornar o valor dentro do método `getItem`. Eis o código:

Teste.java

```
public class Teste extends Fragment
{


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notas, container, false);

    TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edtTeste);
    tx.setText("Testando");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return v;
}


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private String[] tabTitles = {"Teste", "Tela Principal", "Notas"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.

            for(String tab_name : tabTitles) {


            Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            tab.setText(tab_name);

            actionBar.addTab(tab);
            }
        /*  actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));*/
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            //Fragment fragment = new Teste();

        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
            return  new Nota();
            default: return null;
        }

            //return null;


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: Qual o erro/problema que esta acontecendo?

Comment: dentro do metodo getItem, ele nao consegue retornar a classe Teste.

Comment: Você está esperando mesmo a classe `Teste` ou a `Nota`?

Comment: Classe Teste....Eu modifiquei no código

Answer (score 1):

Tente instanciar o **Fragment** assim, ao invés de só dar um *new*:

```
return Fragment.instantiate(context, Teste.class.getName())
```

Na sua `Activity`, o `context` é o **this**, caso você não tenha essa propriedade para outra utilização.